# Php mysqli select where & order by

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, sql-order-by

i've got a problem with the `"order by"` tag at the `mysqli_query`.
Actually it works fine but the order by at the end returns just this error:

> There was an error: Unknown column 'id' in 'order clause'

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemownerid = '".$creatorid."' AND game = 1 AND `game_id` = $gameid order by id desc";
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: are you suer you have a column id in your items table?

Comment: @Anant Why would he need to order by that column, since all the results have the same value there?

Comment: Then there is no column called `id` in the query results.  Why do you think there should be?

Comment: There is no such column in your table. Order by an existing column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the error itself says that there is no `id` column exist in your `items` table and that's why `order by id` fails.

So change it to valid column name. One example is below:-

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemownerid = '".$creatorid."' AND game = 1 AND `game_id` = $gameid ORDER BY <write any existing column name of your items table>  DESC";
```

Note:- please take care of the comment suggested by @tadman. Very useful and necessary